# Rails text_field_tag values are not getting properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi in Rails how to display text_field values. In my index file I am trying display my values in text_field_tag but here is i am getting values in this format

considering bellow code

1) `{:value=>2}`

2) `{:value=>0.3e2}`

But I just want to display in text_field_tag values as

considering bellow code

1)  `2`

2) `300`

How should i reformat it?

is there  any other text_field(I don't want to use it in form field this is just index file for display values I don't want to submit it)

```
   <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3"><%= text_field_tag :amount, value: 2 %></div>

//or 

    <div class="col-xs-4 col-sm-3"><%= text_field_tag :amount, value: expense.amount %></div>
```

Thanks a lot for your valuable answer :)

Comment: `<%= text_field_tag :amount,  2 %>` try this

Comment: Am I asked any wrong question?? why this one down vote?

Comment: @BharatMane should not be down vote.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/text_field_tag), `text_field_tag` accepts the second argument as the value to field. So, pass the value directly (instead of passing it as a hash):

```
<%= text_field_tag :amount, 2 %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are getting hash value as `{:value=>2}`

also you can convert it to integer

```
   expense[:value].to_i
   2.3.4 :003 > 0.3e2.to_i
   => 30




<%= text_field_tag :amount, expense[:value].to_i, class: "your_class", placeholder: 'some placeholder' %>
```

In case if you want static value

```
<%= text_field_tag :amount, 2, class: "your_class", placeholder: 'some placeholder' %>
```

In case if you want to put it in form but not to be submitted make is disable

```
<%= text_field_tag :amount, expense[:value].to_i, disabled: true, class: "your_class", placeholder: 'some placeholder' %>
```

Note: disabled field are not to be subjected to submit with form data, however `:readonly => true` will be wrapped with form datas

in other case just put this field outside the form

Comment: Thanks lot for more explanation :)